# Alamofire on iphone5 (simulator and real device) iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, json, alamofire

My APP use Alamofire library(3.0) to communicate with the server. On iphone5S/iphone6/iphone6-plus it works fine. Today I test it on iphone5, I found the problem: the server answers correct data(JSON), but in the APP, some data fields are missing. Appreciate for any help! code segment and comments below:

```
AFManager.request(.GET, URLString, parameters: params, headers: headers).responseJSON { (json) -> Void in
            if (json.response == nil) {
                completion(nil, "connect to server failed!")
            } else {
                if (json.response?.statusCode)! == 200 {
                    if json.result.isSuccess {
                        let dict = json.result.value //the "value" field's content is a dictionary, having a field named "data", on iphone5, this field is missing, so the rest code can not work correctly. 
                        completion(dict, "")
                    }
                } else if (json.response?.statusCode)! == 401 {
                    completion(nil, "401")
                } else {
                    completion(nil, "unknown error occured")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Check with other device or check with your service team

Comment: Thanks, I did have tried on other device, and simulator, but had no effect

Comment: I have sought the reason, the server is in trouble, on iphone5s/6/6-plus, some initializing data had been downloaded, the APP would not try to download them again, so it works fine. Later on iphone5, it is the first time to run the APP, must download those initializing data first, and the server answers wrong now. Thanks again!